# Is there a way to determine what packages were installed on a particular date, say yesterday for example?

Tags: 10.10, package-management, synaptic

Like a log, or a command or something of that nature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the 'history' feature of the Software Centre:

[image: Software Centre History]

There is also a log file (`/var/log/dpkg.log`). You can view the changes made on a certain date by running:

```
cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep 2010-11-05
```

(replace `2010-11-05` with the date you are querying.)

Comment: There is a log in /var/log/dpkg.log

Comment: Thanks I didn't even see the button there for the history, I suppose it has been there all along (since the Software Center was introduced), oh well, guess I will have to learn to pay more attention.

Comment: AFAIK it was introduced in Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can see a log of what and when packages have been installed, upgraded and removed using the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Just click on:
Applications > Ubuntu Software Centre > History

More information on this functionality is available on the Wiki:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter#History%20section